# php session lost when using paginate

Tags: php, session

Hi my PHP session is lost when using a pagination script. can someone explain why this would happen? I tried putting session_start() at the top off all the paginate script file but that did not work.

```
session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $line['UserName'];
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $line['Password'];
        $_SESSION['session_key'] = $time_started.$secure_session_user.session_id();
        $_SESSION['current_session'] = $line['UserName']."=".$_SESSION['session_key'];
```

Comment: Add some code please. We can't guess the errors in your code...

Comment: What [session configuration](http://php.net/session.configuration) do you use, especially *session.cookies*, *session.use\_only\_cookies* and *session.use\_trans\_sid*?

Comment: i added my session code, its just the standard session code that starts up on login. it works fine, no errors and after the login is complete i have a redirect code that sends a user to the member page. but when the user attempts to use a paginate on that page the session is lost.

Comment: can you explain the proper usage of session.use_cookies would that keep the user logged in no matter where they go on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able, or don't want to show us the code for your pagination, then I can only think of 2 reasons as to why it ain't workin':

1. You've done something wrong somewhere, and don't know it yet. Or;
2. The pagination code you have is using session info for its own stuff (like mine), and maybe it is resetting session info without you knowing it.

All I can do is suggest that you check over your code, make sure you don't have any errors in the way you're handling your sessions, and also check your pagination script.

I hope this helps, though I doubt it will.